# What is the maximum connection timeout to any server?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, http, connection

I have this simple Spring boot based web app that downloads data from several APIs. Some of them don't respond in time, since my `connectionTimeout` is set to somewhat 4 seconds.
As soon as I get rid of `connectionTimeout` setting, I'm getting an exceptions  after 20 or so seconds.

So, my question is, for how long am I able to try to connect to an API and what does it depend on? Where do those 20 seconds come from? What if an API responds after 40 minutes of time and I won't be able to catch that specific moment and just gonna lose data. I don't want that to happen. What are my options?

Here's the code to set the connection. Nothing special.

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(4000);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

Then I retrieve the values via:

```
 myObject.setJsonString(restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class));
```

Comment: Can you share your code you are using to connect to the API. You can specify a connection timeout in most code frameworks. I think you might be trying to fetch a very large data set maybe? Try and fetch a small amount of data to test the connection first.

Comment: edited. It's basically a json and not even a huge one, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Try increasing your timeout. 4 seconds is too little. It will need to connect, formulate data and return. So 4 seconds is just for connecting, by the time it attempts to return anything, your application has already disconnected. Set it to 20 seconds to test it. You can set it to much longer to give the API enough time to complete. This does not mean you app will use up all of the connection timeout time. It will finish as soon as a result is returned. Also API's are not designed to take long. They will perform the task and return the result as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection timeout means that your program couldn't connect to the server at all within the time specified.
The timeout can be configured, as, like you say, some systems may take a longer time to connect to, and if this is known in advance, it can be allowed for. Otherwise the timeout serves as a guard to prevent the application from waiting forever, which in most cases doesn't really give a good user experience.

A separate timeout can normally be configured for reading data (socket timeout). They are not inclusive of each other.

To solve your problem:

1. Check that the server is running and accepting incoming connections.
   You might want to use `curl` or depending on what it is simply your browser to try and connect.
2. If one tool can connect, but the other can't, check your firewall settings and ensure that outgoing connections from your Java program are permitted. The easiest way to test whether this is a problem is to disable anti virus and firewall tools *temporarily*. If this allows the connection, you'll either need to leave the FW off, or better add a corresponding exception.
3. Leave the timeout on a higher setting (or try setting it to 0, which is interpreted as infinite) while testing. Once you have it working, you can consider tweaking it to reflect your server spec and usability requirements.

Edit:

I realised that this doesn't necessarily help, as you did ultimately connect. I'll leave the above standing as general info.

> for how long am I able to try to connect to an API and what does it depend on?

Most likely the server that the API is hosted on. If it is overloaded, response time may lengthen.

> Where do those 20 seconds come from?

Again this depends on the API server. It might be random, or it may be processing each request for a fixed period of time before finding itself in an error state. In this case that might take 20 seconds each time.

> What if an API responds after 40 minutes of time and I won't be able to catch that specific moment and just gonna lose data. I don't want that to happen. What are my options?

1. Use a more reliable API, possibly paying for a service guarantee.
2. Tweak your connection and socket timeouts to allow for the capabilities of the server side, if known in advance.
3. If the response is really 40 minutes, it is a really poor service, but moving on with that assumption - if the dataset is that large, explore whether the API offers a streaming callback, whereby you pass in an OutputStream into the API's library methods, to which it will (asynchronously) write the response when it is ready.
4. Keep in mind that connection and socket timeout are separate things. Once you have connected, the connection timeout becomes irrelevant (socket is established). As long as you begin to receive and continue to receive data (packet to packet) within the socket timeout, the socket timeout won't be triggered either.
5. Use infinite timeouts (set to 0), but this could lead to poor usability within your applications, as well as resource leaks if a server is in fact offline and will never respond. In that case you will be left with dangling connections.

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing your timeout. 4 seconds is too little. 
It will need to connect, formulate data and return. So 4 seconds is just for connecting, by the time it attempts to return anything, your application has already disconnected.

Set it to 20 seconds to test it. You can set it to much longer to give the API enough time to complete. This does not mean you app will use up all of the connection timeout time. It will finish as soon as a result is returned. Also API's are not designed to take long. They will perform the task and return the result as fast as possible

Answer (score 1):

The default and maximum has nothing to do with the the server. It depends on the client platform, but it is around a minute. You can decrease it, but not increase it. Four seconds is far too short. It should be measured in tens of seconds in most circumstances.

And absent or longer connection timeouts do not cause server errors of any kind. You are barking up the wrong tree here.